# Insert space in a specific column without a patern matching (sed or awk) in all lines?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file with a specific column width (250 characters), and I need to insert an space between the column 138 and 139. But in these case I don't have a pattern to match or a delimiter to use.

Is there any way to use sed and/or awk to insert an space between this columns without matching any pattern or using any delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed like this:

```
sed -i.bak -r '/^.{250}$/s/^(.{138})/\1 /' file
```

Comment: +1. I do not think you need the `\2`. `s/^(.{138})/\1 /` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

gawk has `FIELDWIDTHS`, which you could use:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="138 112" '{print $1,$2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/.\{138\}/& /"
```

should be the simpliest